# Refresh browser / link and still "hit" javascript-function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a list through normal html which have this link to a "details" page. URL: `index.php?page=userDetails&usersId=10`. This may be changed if I get the correct solution for my challenge :)

At the "details page" I have made a dropdown which basicly insert (`GET`) a id to PHP and PHP generates content.

The dropdown looks like this

```
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)" class="selectpicker">
    <option data-tokens="10" value="10">user-10</option>
    <option data-tokens="41" value="41">user-41</option>
    <option data-tokens="9" value="9">user-9</option>
    <option data-tokens="8" value="8">User-8</option>
</select>

<!-- This is where PHP-content will be printed..... -->
<div id=\"txtHint\"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

Javascript looks like this (function showUser)

```
function showUser(
{
  if(str == "")
  {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
      return;
  }

  else
  {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }

        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET","logic/do.php?action=ajaxReceive&input="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

The Id (from database) is received as `$_GET[input]` and everything actually works fine, and I can print ID at the moment.

My problem is 2 things:

1) When I refresh browser the ID is not stored. I suppose this can be done by cookie or session, but how do I keep the ID and "insert" it into the function so I stay on user 8, 10, 14 or what ever user I was looking at?

2) The same problem is the actual link where I link from one page to a whole other page. This is neccesary since I am no super-expert so I am reluctant to run everything as pure javascript/jQuery. I fix things best at PHP-side so sometimes I need a little breath :)

I hope you understand my probably rather basic problem...
I am looking forward to some input concerning my little challenge :)

Cheers Nikolaj

Comment: You can store everything into the ``$_SESSION`` variable server side with php but that will only be saved for the current session and will be gone when the browser is restarted.

Comment: How do you want to actually store the ID stuff, on the server? On the client his pc? With session variables, cookies, mysql? The decision depends on how you want to save the information, for how long, where etc?

Comment: @seahorsepip: I do realize that. It is a login site. Sessions are fine with me :)

I have my ID-stuff in mysql. I haven't mad that yet. But that is unproblematic for me. My thought was to generate content in the PHP and here generate fields, form, etc. and work on from there. Isn't that possible?

Meaning ID->javascript->PHP generating new HTML, and the proces may start "over".....? Does that make sense?

Comment: You haven't shown any attempt at storing the selected element. You have to first try something, if it doesn't work, then you can post here asking why.

Comment: What's the point of `data-tokens` when you can get the `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `window.onbeforeunload` to execute a script/function before a page is unloaded. You could send the userID to your PHP script and let that store the userID.

**HTML**

```
<element onbeforeunload="yourFunction()">
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp

**Javascript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { /* Your function send to e.g. PHP here */ }
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){ /* Your function send to e.g. PHP here */ });
```